# Adding functionality for client to change pictures and content of web site

Tags: web

I've been building a static website and the client has suddenly stated that they would like the ability to change the content( words ) and pictures when they feel like it. What is the best way to do this? I could build something, I just want to make sure there isn't already something out there. I need this to be a simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system); a Content Management System.

There are plenty of open-source ones. Wikipedia has a list of many CMS's [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems).

You'll need to decide on a CMS, and set it up. Afterwards, it becomes a matter of styling the CMS after the theme of the static website you have designed. You probably can find many tutorials online, depending on the CMS you choose (that could be part of your criteria).

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of many content-management systems.

[Drupal](http://drupal.org/) is a very popular content-management system with years of development and a very large user base.

You could also use [WordPress](http://wordpress.com/), not strictly a content-management system, but because of its flexibility may be suitable to your or your clients needs.

Here's [an article](http://www.libhound.com/web-development/content-management/free-and-excellent-cms-that-you-probably-want-to-try) on some content-management systems.